# Tomcat Linux server failed issue

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, centos

It is late on a Friday afternoon, and my web application has stopped responding to requests. The server is still reachable, and the Apache Tomcat process is not running–there are no errors in the logs. You want to go home but you can’t until it is fixed. What do you do?

site will run after I restart the server

Server admin told me that its " On further investigation, it came into our understanding that Tomcat application is unable to handle the large number for requests coming into the server at the peak business hours in your website or whenever there is a high traffic in the website. It's the reason the Tomcat service is getting hung up or crashed, then only solution is to restart it, so that Tomcat service running. so other time that said heap Size issue"

But my website generate only maximum 250 persons each day.

Please suggest me what will I do.

Comment: Even 1 person per day can crash it, depends on the code that is behind. But it's weird there's nothing in the log files, I find it hard to believe.

Answer (score 0):

you need to load test your code, the answer given from anyone at this end i.e. from stackoverflow will be very limited due to the limited information provided.

Does it have jmx enabled?
if so then connect via jconsole to your tomcat server and watch what is going on, it sounds to me that it is heapdumping and probably to memory limitation then crashing.

You could start by adding something like this to your setenv.sh

-verbose:gc -Xloggc:/var/log/tomcatXX/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps

http://freddyandersen.wordpress.com/2009/07/14/how-to-enable-verbose-gc-in-tomcat/

You can then look through the gc logs to see how often it is doing a full gc and if indeed there are issues with how it is currently configured.

The problem is you could configure it differently and still face a crash due to memory leaks within the code. this is why load testing and watching jvm via jconsole is important - generally after a full gc the memory usage should drop back down to what default available level if it forks up and up and up until there is less memory available after each full gc you can be sure there is a memory leak within the code.

Take a look at Xms amd XMx settings on your tomcat process if this is low try increasing this generally this is the overall memory configuration for your application (tomcat) this is when it reaches its capacity with the help of a memory leak it will crash.

if Xmx and Xms are set low like 512M definitely try doubling it and if better and have more memory you can go for 2gigs and so forth.

so increasing this will increase its running time but this is also limited to actual available memory of the hardware.

Increasing your Xmx and Xms memory configuration means how much memory it has before it reaches a full GC.  Assuming your solution was high availability and you had beefy boxes you could have stack A with lets say 40Gigs xmx xms settings which after load testing and testing against expected traffic would = 14 hours of actual application with no full gc after which it will go to full gc - this would give 14 hours of uninterrupted application usage - after which you would fail to stack b and let stack a do a full gc

more memory defined =  the longer the gc will take to actually occur =
the longer to gc due to higher memory config = more actual down time whilst it GC's.

An example:

its like a big skip - smaller skip will surely take less time to fill up or empty by hand than a bigger skip. So larger memory config = more time with smaller gc's and longer to get to a full gc but when it gets to full gc it will take longer to empty during which the application does not respond to requests.

The proper solution is to run multiple tomcat servers and either standby or round robin and let them share traffic - this is if you have an apache front end or if not something like an F5 configured to load balance and mark nodes down etc

this should give you some ideas as to what to look for and look at modifying